# How to remove the append data and check at each section in tableview in swift

Tags: ios

I have tableview (grouped).

I have sections.
So each header i have display questions.
EX:-
.How are u?
So the options are:-Fine and not well.

[This is the screen shot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmYe9.png)

This is my code:-

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){


    print("Section \(indexPath.section), Row : \(indexPath.row)")


  if tableView == tableview{


    let cell = tableview.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? QuestionListCell

    let model = questionViewModel.datafordisplay(atindex: indexPath)

    print(model.isSelected)


    cell?.setOptions(OptionsSelected:questionViewModel.datafordisplay(atindex: indexPath))
    print(model.isSelected)
    questionViewModel.isselected = model.isSelected!



    let section = indexPath.section
    let index = indexPath.row
    print(section)
    print(index)


   if !questionViewModel.selectedIndexPaths.contains(indexPath) {

        questionViewModel.selectedIndexPaths.append(indexPath)
        print(questionViewModel.selectedIndexPaths.append(indexPath))


        let questionModel = questionViewModel.titleForHeaderInSection(atsection: section)
        print(questionModel.question)

        print(questionModel.buttontype)

    questionViewModel.button = questionModel.buttontype

    if questionViewModel.button == "1"{

                        //  cell?.imagebutton.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "checkbox_uncheck.png")
                        cell?.imagebutton.setImage(UIImage(named: "checkbox_check.png"), for: .normal)


                        // tableview.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .none
                        self.selected = 1
                        questionViewModel.imagename = "1"

                    }

                    else if questionViewModel.button == "2"{
                        self.selected = 1
                        // cell?.imagebutton.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "radio_uncheck.png")
                        cell?.imagebutton.setImage(UIImage(named: "radio_check.png"), for: .normal)

                        // tableview.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .none
                        questionViewModel.imagename = "2"

                    }

        questionViewModel.question = questionModel.question
        questionViewModel.questionlist(answer: questionViewModel.question!)


        let cell = tableview.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? NH_QuestionListCell

        let model = questionViewModel.datafordisplay(atindex: indexPath)
        print(model.values)

        questionViewModel.answer(answer: model.values!)

        let value: Int = questionModel.id
            let string = String(describing: value)
            //let x: Int? = Int(model.id)

        questionViewModel.question_id = string
        questionViewModel.question(answer: questionViewModel.question_id!)

        print(questionModel.id)


                        }

    print(questionViewModel.button)



  }
```

So according to this .I have 3 array .
1.to append the questions in an array.
2.To append the id in an array.
3.To append the answers in an array.

So according to this output as below.
For question1.
I selected 1st option
So the output comes as:-

```
questionarray:["Gender"]
answerarray:["fine"]
questionid:["1"]
```

But after selecting i decide to select the 2nd option.So first i should remove the append data from the 3 arrays.Then needed to append the current data.So the data should as below.

```
  questionarray:["Gender"]
        answerarray:["not well"]
        questionid:["1"]
```

So how to do here.How to check here.Same way i need at every section .So to do?

Comment: how to implement

Comment: @Tushar Katyal can u suggest to to implement?

Comment: how to check at each section ?

Comment: why are you removing the array values, just change the values in particular index.